# Can't debug correctly Windows drivers with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, driver

I've written a Windows driver sample (WDM) with Visual Studio but I'm encountering issues when trying to debug it. The target is running in a Virtual Machine (VMware)
I've followed the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272(v=vs.85).aspx) to configure everything.
It's compiling fine but there are problems when debugging.

I have tried various configurations and have different problems on each.

**Visual Studio 2013 Preview on Win7 (host) / Win8.1 Preview (target) - VMware**

It seems the debugger isn't working properly. Indeed it's like if nothing was loaded, the Modules Window is empty, when I click on "Break all" nothing is happening. As you can see in the logs, the debugger session isn't created.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]
Logs: http://pastebin.com/DfVzGR4Z

**Visual Studio 2012 on Win7 (host) / Win8 (target) - VMware**

It's working correctly at the first try but if I stop the debugger to modify the driver, it'll freeze the VM. I'll then have to restart the VM, Visual Studio and kill the process ntkd.exe because otherwise I have these errors:

- Failure to create process instance prevents debugging
- Unable to start (null), Error 80004005. (Unspecified error)
- Followed by a crash of VS (Event Name: CLR20r3)

I've tried with other samples downloaded from the MSDN but it's the same problem.

I've been stuck on these issues for weeks and I'm starting to desperate, so any help would be appreciate. I haven't tried WinDDK but since VS has everything needed, I don't see why I couldn't use it normally.

Comment: I had similar issue with Visual Studio Communities 2017 --> WinDevEval (virtualbox win10 evaluation)
Debuggee somehow freezes -- I tried to look into the target computer using WinObj.exe and found that driver was installed correct, I then created a basic MFC application which open and closes the handle to the device driver and that works (when running in administrator mode) - somehow the debugging is not getting further

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to forget using Visual Studio for driver development/debugging because, on my opinion, is not solid enough.

But targetting the debugging process, it is better to install [VisualDDK](http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/) and then launch vmmon/vmmon64.

In the installed application you will find a folder named "target" with an application named DDKLaunchMonitor.exe, install it in the virtual machine (it will create a boot menu option to activate kernel debugging)

When you want to debug your driver, launch vmmon, activate the option to launch windbg at vm startup, start your vm and when windows boots it will load windbg and attach to the vm.

The install your driver as desired and learn windbg.

I know this answer does not solve you problem with VS but using windbg directly is faster and better.

Comment: Forgot something. I don't remember if VirtualKD comes with VisualDDK package, if not, use it too. Is on the same page.

Comment: Do you know if VisualDDK supports WDK 8? I can't configure the %WDKPATH% value in the setup wizard.

Comment: I didn't use WDK 8 altough installed, but you can type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\" where it installed by default. Don't worry because for debugging you will not need it. Run VMMON(VMMON64) and press "debugger path" button to locate windbg and tick "start debugger automatically".

Comment: VisualDDK was created mainly for integrate driver development with VS. You may not need it using VS2012. I recommend it mainly for make debugging easier with vm's using vmmon/windbg.

Comment: the install of VisualDDK current version expect WDK to be seperately installed, and eventhough VisualStudio is proper installed with debugging tools - I think this solution is a going two steps back - at least the installer of the thing should work before proceeding with this

Comment: @serup you are talking about something that is 5 years in the past! Nowadays WDK is better and more integrated with VS.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri, well issue still exist in VS somehow the debuggee is frozen which renderes it unuseful - that is why I tried using VisualDDK, however that was also not useful

Comment: @serup Although VS is improved, I still prefer windbg for drivers and VirtualKD. The only problem on Win10 is the extra work to replace kdcom.dll

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri - I actually think I read somewhere that VS is using the Windbg tool

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with: Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Windows 10 host, Windows 10 target, VirtualBox with host only network.

Provisioning and remote driver deployment worked, but the debugger would not connect.

**Edit**: In the last step of provisioning in VS2015 the `Host IP` can be selected. The manual method below is an alternative.

The [manual setup guide for kernel mode debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346(v=vs.85).aspx) says to run the following:

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings net hostip:w.x.y.z port:n
```

Visual Studio automatically runs these during the provisioning process. Notice the `hostip` parameter - this has to be the address of the connecting machine (the one with the debugger) **on the interface it uses to connect to the target**. Visual Studio may set this incorrectly if you have multiple network interfaces. In my case the VirtualBox host only network created the extra network interface.

Provision the target machine in VS, if you haven't already. Then **run the two** `bcdedit` **commands above and reboot the target machine**. After this, the debugger should connect properly.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem. The windbg connection is hang. I found there is something wrong in my configuration for Kernel mode debugger settings( Visual studio 2012 Driver->test->Configuration). I set the port simply com1. Actually, it should be \.\pipe\com_1.Then it works
In your case, there maybe other configuration problems. You can check through the points on webpage http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/545835/Kernel-Mode-Debugging-in-a-VM-using-Visual-Studio.

Comment: However, although every time the debugger immediate can connect to the virtual machine after the break, sometimes  it stops after the symbolpath search and executable path search quite often after the target virtual machine reboot. Anyway, I agree kernel debug in Visual Studio 2012 is time wasting.